# How to Using Android SpannableString and MaskFilterSpan to blur some text from TextView as expected?

Tags: android, blur, spannablestring

What i expected is like this.
[image]
This is a movie review,when some words may spoiler story,it will be wrapped by these tags [spoiler][/spoiler].
so i wrote method find out every spoiler words's start index and end index,then using MaskFilterSpan to blur it.

But the result not well.

[image]

If i just replace MaskFilterSpan to StrikethroughSpan or BackgroundColorSpan,it works perfect.
[image][image]

My code:

```
private void testBlurText() {
    String text = "Alec Baldwin nailed his job; \n" +
            "The animators nailed their job (seriously, the art style and changes were amazing);\n" +
            "The ideas guy nailed his job ([spoiler]It's all the imagination of the kid[/spoiler]);\n" +
            "The writers just let the story down :( ([spoiler]Although at the beginning it's clear that the whole shebang is the older kid's imagination, the writers probably realised that the script was too short and so the end got changed to something that makes no sense. Why would Tim receive the kid for a second time? - unless it was all a dream...[/spoiler] ).\n" +
            "\n" +
            "All in all, a good movie, amazing acting and animating, partly let down by a badly written ending to the story. 8/10.";
    SpannableString spanText = new SpannableString(text);
    List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> spoilersContainer = new ArrayList<>();
    getSpoilerIndex(text, 0, spoilersContainer);
    for (Pair<Integer, Integer> pair : spoilersContainer) {
        spanText.setSpan(new MaskFilterSpan(new BlurMaskFilter(20, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL)), pair.first, pair.second, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        Logger.d("SpoilerIndex:" + pair.toString());
    }
    tvTestBlurText.setText(spanText);
}

private void getSpoilerIndex(String rawComment, int beginIndex, List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> spoilersContainer) {
    int startIndex = rawComment.indexOf("[spoiler]", beginIndex);
    int endIndex = rawComment.indexOf("[/spoiler]", beginIndex);
    if (startIndex != -1 && endIndex != -1) {
        spoilersContainer.add(new Pair<>(startIndex, endIndex + "[/spoiler]".length()));
        getSpoilerIndex(rawComment, endIndex + "[/spoiler]".length(), spoilersContainer);
    }
}
```

Are there any wrong,or just a bug of MaskFilterSpan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It renders correctly if you set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` on your Activity in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

BlurMaskFilter is not supported with hardware acceleration.

You can check Unsupported Drawing Operations here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html